# My Huawei E303F dongle detected but unable to connect to the internet in ubundu 15.10?

Tags: internet, usb-modem

I installed driver for my Huawei E303F on my Ubuntu 15.10. It is installed successfully but not able to connect internet. No connection available. Huawei E303 is working fine in this.

Comment: How about : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008275

Answer (score 0):

Install ppp(it may already have been installed). Then try your luck with [Sakis3G](http://www.sakis3g.com/). It is a very good and easy to use package for connecting to internet using USB dongles.

run the following commands in terminal for installing ppp and sakis3G:

```
sudo apt-get install ppp 
sudo wget "http://www.sakis3g.com/downloads/sakis3g.tar.gz" -O sakis3g.tar.gz
sudo tar -xzvf sakis3g.tar.gz
sudo chmod +x sakis3g
```

now to launch it, run this:

```
./sakis3g --interactive
```

Comment: Thank you so much.   But after launching  "./sakis3g --interactive
",  I tried to connect through  "connect with 3G-> USB device -> Huawei mobile''.  Then it asking root password  after that it asks "select modem  interface of USB device that provides modem capabilities:  Interface#0 or  Interface#1".   I chose Interface#0. But It shows "error occurred:  Port /dev/ttyUSB0 is currently occupied by 816 ModemManager.  "  Please help me to overcome this difficulties.  Thank you.

Comment: run this  `ps all | grep ModemManager` if you can see any line as output. Try killing the process by running `sudo killall -9 ModemManager`. And then try with sakis3g

Comment: Thank you.   After running the command  "ps all | grep ModemManager"and "sudo killall -9 ModemManager".   I tried to connect through sakis3g.  Again I got trouble and it shows like " Port /dev/ttyUSB0 is currently occupied by 14281 ModemManager. "

Comment: ''Also I got the output in terminal after run with sakis3g as "(zenity:31213): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_connection_register_object: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
".